# Mapping from old contract to the new one

Tags: solidity, everscale

trying somehow move mapping to upgrade after vm.resetStorage().
Put one into the cell and try to:

wallets_mapping = abi.decode(
wallets_mapping_cell,
(mapping(address => BalanceWalletStruct))
);

It works but get response:

wallet_mapping == '{}'

Please advice how to move mapping from old contract to the new one and don't lose it by the way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [How to upgrade contracts](https://docs.everscale.network/develop/smart-contracts/how-to-upgrade-contracts) and if the issue is not resolved, then add information about your contest